# Can $_GET be positioned in any position in the url?

Tags: php, url

I already have a URL which looks like this,
    `/admin/add_to_list/' .$payer. '/' .$tid. '?credit=1`

knowing that i already have a `$_GET` in my url, I want to add another thing on my url. Is it possible that my new url will look like this,

```
/admin/add_to_list/' .$payer. '/' .$tid. '?credit=1/silentmode
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tested it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example will result in fetching the same URL as the first, but now `$_GET['credit']` will be equal to `"1/silentmode"` instead of `"1"`.

Path elements must always come before the query string, which itself must always come before the fragment. That is simply the syntax of a URL - after all, you wouldn't expect `example.com.www//http:` to work, would you?

Comment: Thanks for the enlightenment.

Answer (score 1):

Use the ampersand (&) to have multiple $_GET values. Example:

```
index.php?name=joe&surname=smith
```

You can then retrieve them individually like so:

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
$surname = $_GET['surname'];
```

Answer (score 0):

No. Anything after the first `?` until the first `#` (if any) is the query string.

You need to deconstruct your URL and put the extra path element before the query string.